# How do I use JPA's entityManager.getReference in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12828955/3395716 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184186/3395716 and many others mention of some `enitityManager.getReference()` method, which can be used to avoid making unnecessary select queries to the database.

I am having similar issue in spring boot app, when trying to save an object to the database, using `CRUDRepository`. My class looks like,

```
class StudentSubject {
    String studentId;
    @ManyToOne
    private Subject subject;
    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
}
```

I have to unnecessarily make `find()` calls to get the student and subject objects from the database, only to pass them to `StudentSubjectRepository` to `save()` them. But I already have the primary keys of both subject and student. So I would like to use them instead, and `entityManager` looks like what I need.

But I have no idea where this entityManager comes from, or if there is any equivalent to it in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's injected normally, Spring Boot has nothing to do with it (Spring Boot is just Spring albeit with some configuration differences).

Just add

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

to your class and you can access the raw `EntityManager` object and all that it offers. There's nothing wrong with using it, you can't get everything done with repositories.

Answer (score 8):

If you use [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) interface for your repository instead of `CRUDRepository`, you will gain access to `getOne(id)` method which is the equivalent of the `entityManager.getReference`.

Comment: Not really, in general a Controller should know as least as possible about the low-level retrieval of data from the database i.e. entityManager. The usage of specialized repositories adds another abstraction layer which in testing , can easily mocked and injected.